# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode giving different results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

Here is a nice simple line in C#:

`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#127866;")`

It should return , and if I run that from my unit tests, or from LinqPad, it does.

Other times it returns `&#127866;`, for instance, if I run it from my Asp.Net MVC project (running on .Net 4.0).  It also does that if I run the line from the Immediate window in Visual Studio 2015.

`WebUtility.HtmlDecode` returns the same results.

Environment.Version return 4.0.30319.42000 in all cases.

Is there a more consistent HtmlDecode out there someplace?

Comment: Wait, a functioln which returns a beer?? Holly molly, that's new for me :D

Comment: `&#127863;` returns  if you are so inclined

Comment: `U+1F37A BEER MUG` is a Unicode 6.0 character, for which you need at least .NET 4.5 running on at least Windows 8. That's not to say you couldn't have an `HtmlDecode` on earlier platforms that correctly decomposes this entity into its constituent surrogates internally, of course, but it might help explain the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a fix using `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(127866)`

That does mean I have to parse the value a bit, but I've done that before.